# Disable Liquibase temporarily in JHipster 2.26

Tags: liquibase, jhipster

I am using JHipster as a tool to teach Software Engineering. I would like to teach JHipster incrementally to soften the learning curve . In this regard, please, I'd like to know the smartest way to temporarily disable Liquibase . I prefer to use the JPA2 DDL auto functionality at the begining of the Academic course (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-jpa) .
Thank you very much for this awesome AngularJS + Spring Boot generator.

Answer (score 19):

I'm using jihipster 3.12, in Jhipster 3.12, in your src\main\resource\config\application-dev.yml

change profiles setup to add "no-liquibase" like this:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
        include: swagger, no-liquibase
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hey! Does entity generation and other JH stuff still work? Is it possible to start liquibase again for example when going to production? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can add the profile no-liquibase when build. I ussually use below config:

```
 <plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <executable>true</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>--spring.profiles.active=prod,no-liquibase</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

You can prefer some useful profiles in Constants if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to disable liquibase, by commenting the includes in the master.xml file.

But every time on adding/updating an entity, the master.xml file is updated. This will again execute liquibase on subsequent startups.

I had all the tables generated and I wanted to completely disable liquibase. For this I commented out liquibase plugins and dependencies from the pom.xml.

This gave a few compilation errors in a few liquibase related java classes, which I commented out.

Now liquibase does not start any more on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out all `include` lines from `master.xml`. This will not actually disable liquibase and it will still create the `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock` tables, but it will prevent it from applying any changesets.

Comment: Thank you! I think that I will adopt a hybrid approach : liquibase for master data (init data) and Hibernate auto DDL data for custom entities