# Is there a way to generate jHipster code without the Liquibase? Or to Disable the Liqibase ? JHipster 4.7.0

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

Is there a way to generate jHipster code without Liquibase?
Or Is there a jHipster generator for database scripts in some kind of separate project of database scripts like in Oracle, MySQL, P SQL etc.
What I mean is Liqibase does not meet my needs, like I want to create tablespaces for my Oracle DB, create a user and grant privileges to it and then create my SQL scripts with in pure SQL not in Liquibase XML file as I want my table data to reside in my tablespace and want to specify the size of columns based on my requirements. And when I'm done with creating the SQL file I just have to run the jar file for all the DB work.

If there is not an option for generating schema without Liquibase. I'm considering disabling the Liquibase and generate the tables manually. Can I disable the Liqibase? There are some online suggestions but for jHipster 3.12 but I have not tried it yet.

[Disable Liquibase temporarily in JHipster 2.26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559042/disable-liquibase-temporarily-in-jhipster-2-26)

Answer (score 4):

- Yes you can use the `no-liquibase` profile ([here is the documentation](http://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/)), and Liquibase will not run anymore
- However, JHipster will still generate the Liquibase files for you: you can just ignore them, or even delete them

I personally often use that profile, even if I use Liquibase a lot, as this speeds up deployment (of course, I only use it when I don't modify my database, but I'm not modifying it all the time). So this is nice trick to know, whether you like Liquibase or not.

Then, I'm pretty sure you can do your database-specific scripts with Liquibase, or run them before Liquibase, so maybe this is another solution you could use.

Comment: I have already tried to run scripts before Liquibase but when the test is run it fails and gives the error due to Liqibase as it tries to find my tables in Liquibase XML file. But the project run success fully if I skip tests using -DskipTests.

Comment: Also Liquibase allows you to write SQL instaed of XML if you prefer. In my company we added migration scripts using SQL as its convenient to update when you have a lot of JSON values to insert http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html