# how disable liquibase in jhipster 7.7.0

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase

I'd like to know how can I temporarily disable Liquibase in JHipster 7.7.0 there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559042/disable-liquibase-temporarily-in-jhipster-2-26) I tried this suggested [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42015979/14994239) but it shows this error

> org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException:
> Property 'spring.profiles.include' imported from location 'class path
> resource [config/application-dev.yml]' is invalid in a profile
> specific resource [origin: class path resource
> [config/application-dev.yml] - 43:14]

EDIT

I want to disable it because everytime I run `mvnw` I got this message and it takes **minutes** before the app get started on my localhost

> 2022-05-12 22:49:44.878 DEBUG 13536 --- [  restartedMain]
> m.p.g.config.LiquibaseConfiguration      : Configuring Liquibase
> 2022-05-12 22:49:45.380  WARN 13536 --- [on-rd-vs-task-1]
> t.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Starting Liquibase
> asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maven project**

In order to disable Liquibase in Maven-based project, you need to edit pom.xml file and add the new profile in the profiles node.

```
...
  <profile>
      <id>no-liquibase</id>
      <properties>
          <profile.no-liquibase>,no-liquibase</profile.no-liquibase>
      </properties>
  </profile>
 ...
```

pom.xml
If you’re using IntelliJ IDEA you can do it conveniently using Maven menu and Profiles group as well.

source: https://blog.mestwin.net/how-to-disable-liquibase-in-your-jhipster-project

---

Another option is to run your application like that `./mvnw -Pdev,no-liquibase`

source: https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/#spring-profiles-switches

Comment: thank you for the answer, I already have this this configuration in pom.xml when I generated my JHipster app but liquibase doesn't get disabled, I don't know if I have to change something else..

Comment: I edited my answer with another alternative, I hope it's help 

Comment: Actually It's disabled I can see the message on console, but the problem the problem I mentioned in the question doesn't get resolved, I thought If I disable liquibase I won't get that error but it's not the case :( maybe I should make a new question about that issue .. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @hakimamaarouf , Could you share your .yo-rc.json file? I run the hipster 7.7.0 version here and it's taken too long to get started. The problem I detected is the following https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/12461 .